# SQL Table Creation from Joining Data

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Before I lay out the question, here’s the information concerning my data:

```
Table Name: dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
Columns: MMSI, Message_ID, Time, Vessel_Name, Ship_Type, IMO, Dimension_to_Bow, Dimension_to_stern, Dimension_to_port, Dimension_to_starboard, Draught, Longitude, Latitude
```

I need to create a New Table. This following is what I need in the table:

I am interested in all this data, **but I only need Message_ID’s that are 1 or 3. ** Problem is, Message_ID’s 1 and 3 **lack** the following: (Which is only available with Message_ID's 5.)

```
Vessel_Name,  Ship_Type, IMO, 
Dimension_to_Bow, 
Dimension_to_stern,
Dimension_to_port, 
Dimension_to_starboard, 
Draught
```

For Message_ID’s 1 and 3, those columns are marked NULL. All they have is

```
Longitude, 
Latitude, 
Time, 
MMSI
```

(which are **all marked NULL** for **Message_ID's equaling 5**)

MMSI is the primary key in this instance. Message_ID’s 1, 3 and 5 will all have MMSI numbers that represent a given ship. These MMSI’s though are reoccurring as each ship sends out multiple Message’s of type 1, 3 and 5. So say we have an MMSI of 210293000, This number will be alongside several Message_ID’s different types. So what I need to do is grab all the Message_ID’s that are 1 and 3 and append the information from the Message_ID’s that are 5 to the1’s and 3’s. So in that, the columns are no longer NULL.

Last but not least, I have to select only Message_ID 1’s and 3’s that fall within the following:

```
Where Latitude > 55 and Latitude <85 and Longitude > 50 and Longitude < 141;
```

Example of how a few columns look:

```
MMSI/ Message_ID /Time/Ship_type/Vessel_Name/Latitude/Longitude

21029300, 3, 2012-06-01, NULL, NULL, 56.528003, 85.233443

21029300, 5, 2012-07-01, 70, RIO_CUBAL, NULL, NULL

2109300, 1, 2012-08-01, NULL, NULL, 57.432345, 131.123343

2109300, 1, 2012-09-01, NULL, NULL, 62.432345, 121.123343

2109300, 1, 2012-09-02, NULL, NULL, 65.432345, 140.123343

21029300, 5, 2012-08-01, 70, RIO_CUBAL, NULL, NULL
```

The end result would be as follows from this data:

```
21029300, 3, 2012-06-01, 70, RIO_CUBAL, 56.528003, 85.233443

2109300, 1, 2012-08-01, 70, RIO_CUBAL, 57.432345, 131.123343

2109300, 1, 2012-09-01, 70, RIO_CUBAL, 62.432345, 121.123343

2109300, 1, 2012-09-02, 70, RIO_CUBAL, 65.432345, 140.123343
```

Thanks!

Comment: for one, your question is hard to read. i improved it, but you could polish it further. then we'd probably be more interested if you could something you tried and that failed for one reason or another (please mention the reason).

Comment: For a given ship you have multiple rows with `Message_ID` being `1` or `3`? And you have multiple rows with `Message_ID` being `5` for those ships, too? How do you intend to connect them? Meaning: Which 3-valued row do you want to connect to which 5-valued row, for example?

Comment: That's exactly it, a single ship will blast out many message 1, 3 and 5. but each message contains specific information. The message 1 and 3's have lat and long but don't have vessel name or type etc.. They only blast out that information in message 5's. But I need that info as well. So i need to create a new table with only the message 1 and 3's (within my given lat longs), but with the information from the message 5's included. (as it is not included with 1's and 3's)

Comment: If you see in my sample table: the first row has two nulls. How would you create a new table with those nulls filled in by take the information from the second row (As they have the same MMSI number and hence are the same ship)

Comment: My questions stands, then: How do you decide, which row of type `5` you want to choose for the rows of type `1` and `3`? Try to provide some meaningful sample data AND the desired result. By "meaningful" I mean rows for one ship but with at least two different rows of type `1`, two different rows of type `3` and two different rows of type `5`.

Comment: I guess it really doesn't matter which row of type 5.. The information I am looking for will be consistent throughout the type 5 rows. The only difference within a row of type 5 will be the time stamp. I'll try and add some more sample data to teh table above, and what i am looking to produce

Comment: Is this a one-time thing (so a quick and somehow dirty solution would be fine) or do you intend to use the solution on a regular base in some form of application?

Comment: a one time thing, im going to save the data and then use it in arcgis

Comment: Even if the query does not create a new table that is fine.. As long as the data has been queried  I can just save it as a .csv

Answer (score 0):

In a single transaction, create the new table, use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to transfer the data from `DecodedCSVMessages_Staging` into the new table, then `DELETE FROM ...` to delete the old data from `DecodedCSVMessages_Staging`.

Comment: I'm somewhat new to database, I'm not sure how that would look. Also, I do not have permission to alter the existing table

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records. I guess you don't have to delete the old data, but I was assuming you wanted to move, not copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the Type 1 and Type 3 messages, with added information from a join to the first corresponding Type 5 record in your data.  (If there is no corresponding Type 5 record, you will get nulls for those fields.)  Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M13.MMSI, M13.Message_ID, M13.Time, M13.Latitude, M13.Longitude,
M5.Vessel_Name, M5.Ship_Type, M5.IMO, M5.Dimension_to_Bow
M5.Dimension_to_stern, M5.Dimension_to_port, 
M5.Dimension_to_starboard, M5.Draught
FROM dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging M13
JOIN (
SELECT MMSI, Time, Vessel_Name, Ship_Type, IMO, Dimension_to_Bow
Dimension_to_stern, Dimension_to_port, Dimension_to_starboard, 
Draught
FROM dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
WHERE Message_ID = 5
ORDER BY Time
) M5
ON M5.MMSI = M13.MMSI
WHERE M13.Message_ID IN (1, 3)
AND M13.Latitude > 55
AND M13.Latitude < 85
AND M13.Longitude > 50
AND M13.Longitude < 141
ORDER BY M13.Time
```

If this returns the data you want, then create a new table and insert the records using [INSERT INTO NewTable SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx/css#OtherTables).

Please be aware that MMSI is not a primary key, either in the old table or in the new table.  Primary keys (PK) have to be unique, and in this case you have multiple entries for each MMSI.

When you create your new table, you should add an integer IDENTITY field so that it will have a PK.  This IDENTITY field isn't included in the insert statement, but it is automatically populated with an incrementing integer.  That way each record gets a unique PK, which is highly desirable.

**EDITED** to use a `DISTINCT` on the outer query.

Comment: When I attempt this query I get red lines on the initial select criteria, for example, if I hover my mouse of M13.MMSI it says: 

the multi-part identifier "M13.MMSI" could not be bound

Comment: @criticalfix I think you're joining a set of exactly one row here, so this will probably not work as desired.

Comment: Thanks @papatoob and @dpalm - I didn't think through how the `TOP 1` would work.  I need to rethink and edit this.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account all the information from the comments section (especially about the one-time-thing note) you can try the following SQL statement. This will, however, only work if the relevant data of the "type 5" messages really is consistent as you stated!

```
SELECT Messages.MMSI
    ,Messages.Message_ID
    ,Messages.TIME
    ,Type5Messages.Vessel_Name
    ,Type5Messages.Ship_Type
    ,Type5Messages.IMO
    ,Type5Messages.Dimension_to_Bow
    ,Type5Messages.Dimension_to_stern
    ,Type5Messages.Dimension_to_port
    ,Type5Messages.Dimension_to_starboard
    ,Type5Messages.Draught
    ,Messages.Longitude
    ,Messages.Latitude
INTO [DataBaseName].[dbo].[YourNewTableName]
FROM dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging Messages
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT MMSI
        ,Vessel_Name
        ,Ship_Type
        ,IMO
        ,Dimension_to_Bow
        ,Dimension_to_stern
        ,Dimension_to_port
        ,Dimension_to_starboard
    FROM dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
    WHERE Messages.Message_ID = 5
    ) Type5Messages
    ON Messages.MMSI = Type5Messages.MMSI
WHERE Messages.Message_ID IN (1,3)
    AND Messages.Latitude > 55
    AND Messages.Latitude < 85
    AND Messages.Longitude > 50
    AND Messages.Longitude < 141;
```

In this statement you select all "type 1" and "type 3" rows and join them with all "type 5" rows that have the same `MMSI` value. If the "type 5" information is consistent regarding the selected columns, there will be only one entry for each "type 5" row and therefore every "type 1" and "type 3" row will appear only once. You should definitely do some testing, though.
The `INTO [DataBaseName].[dbo].[YourNewTableName]` line (which you will have to adjust naming-wise) creates a new table (if you choose a name that has not been used yet) with the original table's data types and inserts the selected rows. You might want to alter this table later on if you need indixes, keys, relationships or whatsoever.

Comment: I just changed the initial `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in case there are no "type 5" messages for some ships.