# SQL AdvancedQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following data in a table called: dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging

**Here is a sample of the data:**

```
MMSI     Message_ID    Time     Ship_Type  Vessel_Name   Latitude   Longitude

2102930      3       2012-06-01     NULL      NULL       56.528003  85.233443

2102930      5       2012-07-01      70     RIO_CUBAL      NULL      NULL

2109300      1       2012-08-01     NULL      NULL       57.43234   131.123343

2109300      1       2012-09-01     NULL      NULL       62.432345  121.123343

2109300      1       2012-09-02     NULL      NULL       65.432345  140.123343

2109300      5       2012-08-01      70     RIO_CUBAL      NULL       NULL

2225555      1       2012-08-01     NULL      NULL       66.432345  143.123343

2225555      1       2012-09-01     NULL      NULL       25.432345  145.123343

2225555      5       2012-08-01      70      RIO_II        NULL       NULL
```

What I need is as follows:

- An MMSI number is a unique number that represents a ship. A ship sends out different information in unique Message types. I am interested in only Message_ID 1's and 3's as they have Latitudinal and Longitudinal Information. MMSI's will be reoccuring in this database (as demonstrated in the data above)
- Problem is, I need information about the ship which is unfortunately only available in Message_ID 5's. such as Vessel_name and Ship_type.
- I only need ships which fall within the following longitude and latitude
- **Ship_Type might change! In which case it must reflect the later date**

  **where Latitude > 55 and Latitude <85 and Longitude > 50 and Longitude < 141;**

**The result of querying the data** would produce the following (Of which I will save to CSV format as I am using this information to build point features in ArcGIS)

```
MMSI     Message_ID    Time    Ship_Type  Vessel_Name   Latitude   Longitude

2102930      3       2012-06-01     70     RIO_CUBAL    56.528003  85.233443

2109300      1       2012-08-01     70     RIO_CUBAL    57.43234   131.123343

2109300      1       2012-09-01     70     RIO_CUBAL    62.432345  121.123343

2109300      1       2012-09-02     70     RIO_CUBAL    65.432345  140.123343

2225555      1       2012-08-01     70      RIO_II      66.432345  143.123343
```

- So all the Message_ID 5's are gone
- The second to last row is gone (as the Latitude was only 25.432345)
- The information Ship_Type and Vessel_Name has been added to the
  Message_ID 1's and 3's by way of linking using the MMSI.

RESTRAINTS:

1. Cannot create a new table (do no have access)
2. There are over a billion rows of data in this database (only about 4.3 million that meet the latitude/longitude constraints though

**WHAT MIGHT THE QUERY BE??? tHANKS!**

Comment: Can Ship_Type and Vessel_Name change for same MMSI?

Comment: What is the difference to [yesterday's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828568/sql-table-creation-from-joining-data)? There are detailed answers to start working with.

Comment: @dpalm "It shouldn't" = "it does". It will require further complexity to gain this answer, it is up to you to tell us if the performance hit is too great. I will update my answer shortly to reflect this.

Comment: Yesterdays question lacked clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
; WITH positions AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Message_ID
       , "Time"
       , Latitude
       , Longitude
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID IN (1, 3)
  AND    Latitude  > 55
  AND    Latitude  < 85
  AND    Longitude > 50
  AND    Longitude < 141
)
, details AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Ship_Type
       , Vessel_Name
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY MMSI ORDER BY "Time" DESC) As row_num
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID = 5
)
SELECT positions.MMSI
     , positions.Message_ID
     , positions."Time"
     , details.Ship_Type
     , details.Vessel_Name
     , positions.Latitude
     , positions.Longitude
FROM   positions
 INNER
  JOIN details
    ON details.MMSI    = positions.MMSI
   AND details.row_num = 1 -- Limit to "latest" ship details per MMSI
```

Comment: Upvoted this. Downvoting is really harsh considering OP didn't even post an attempt.

Comment: @AlecHenderson_v1.00 thanks. But to be honest I'm not sure why it was downvoted in the first place? I made a few modifications based on the OP comments so the answer was a moving target for a minute or two but as far as I can tell this will give the correct result. Feedback from Mr(s) Downvoter would be appreciated.

Comment: worked! Thank you so much (still querying but the data being displayed thus far is exactly what I need)

Comment: I was wondering if you could add a new part to this! If an MMSI has any point within the latitude and longitudes specified, then I would need all the points associated with that MMSI, even if they do not fall within the limits specified! :S

Comment: @dpalm I suggest you start a new question for that part :) Include a reference to this question in your new one to help others.

Comment: how do i reference a question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873241/sql-query-adjustment hopefully people dont freak out about the question this time around lol..

Answer (score 1):

I would think it relatively simple... something like..

```
select
      MS.MMSI,
      MS.Message_ID,
      MS.Time,
      Ship.Ship_Type,
      Ship.Vessel_Name,
      MS.Latitude,
      MS.Longitude
   from
      dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging MS
         JOIN dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging Ship
            on MS.MMSI = Ship.MMSI
           AND Ship.Message_ID = 5
   where
          MS.Message_ID in ( 1, 3 )
      AND MS.Latitude > 55
      AND MS.Latitude < 85
      AND MS.Longitude > 50
      AND MS.Longitude < 141
```

I would also suggest an index on

( MMSI, Message_ID, Latitude, Longitude )

so it covers as much of the criteria you are looking for and join conditions as well

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH SHIP_CTE (Vessel_name,Ship_type,MMSI)
(SELECT Vessel_name, Ship_type,MMSI FROM DecodedCSVMessages_Staging WHERE Message_Id=5)
SELECT A.MMSI,Message_ID, Time,B.Ship_Type,B.Vessel_Name, Latitude,
Longitude FROM DecodedCSVMessages_Staging  A JOIN SHIP_CTE B ON A.MMSI=B.MMSI
where Latitude > 55 and Latitude <85 and Longitude > 50 and Longitude < 141
```

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, there is a way to filter before the staging table.  BPO, I think.  It was the command line utility to read CSV into a staging table.  Reducing rows to 4% would likely be a good tactic if possible.

As I remember you could even split a CSV into related tables.  I worked with this a while back on a 2 million row daily import into 8-10 tables that completed in less than 30 seconds.

Comment: I think you mean **BCP** :-)

Answer (score 0):

Saw original selected post, worked out my solution with "most recent ID=5 entry", then saw updated winning post. Tossing mine in anyway, to show how it could be done without the CTE. (I know people love CTEs, but I find them harder to read and understand than simple subqueries.)

```
SELECT
   M13.MMSI
  ,M13.Message_ID
  ,M13.Time
  ,RecentM5.Ship_Type
  ,RecentM5.Vessel_Name
  ,M13.Latitude
  ,M13.Longitude
 from dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging M13
  inner join (--  Most recent "Message_ID = 5" entry for each MMSI (i.e. most recent name)
              select MMSI, Ship_Type, Vessel_Name
               from (--  All MMSI, set "Ranking" = 1 for the most recent entry
                     select MMSI, Ship_Type, Vessel_Name, row_number() over (partition by MMSI order by Time desc) Ranking
                      from dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
                      where Message_ID = 5) AllM5
               where Ranking = 1) RecentM5
   on RecentM5.MMSI = M13.MMSI
 where M13.Message_ID <> 5  --  Assumes Message_ID can only be 1,3,5, ortherwise use (slower) IN clause
  and M13.Latitude between 55 and 85
  and M13.Longitude between 50 and 141
```

As for "over a billion rows", best way to address that is with indexes... but it seems likely you'll have to read every row in the table at least once.  While indexes on Latitude, Longitude, and Message_ID all suggest themselves, the nature of the data implies a low cardinality -- that is, significant portions of your data will fall within your filtering criteria, making table scans the most efficient way of reading the data. Do you have to worry about locking or blocking issues?

Answer (score -1):

I think this query would do.

```
SELECT MMSI, MESSAGE_ID, TIME, SHIP_TYPE, VESSEL_NAME, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM
(
SELECT MMSI, MESSAGE_ID, TIME, SHIP_TYPE, VESSEL_NAME, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM TABLE where Latitude > 55 and Latitude <85 and Longitude > 50 and Longitude < 141  AND MESSAGE_ID IN (3,1) ) A
(
SELECT MMSI, MESSAGE_ID, TIME, SHIP_TYPE, VESSEL_NAME, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM TABLE WHERE
MESSAGE_ID= 5) B WHERE A.MMSI=B.MMSI AND A.MESSAGE_ID IN (3,1)
```

Thanks
Niraj Rathi