# SQL Query Adjustment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**The initial question was as follows:** [SQL AdvancedQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850908/sql-advancedquery) It is recommended to take a look at the initial question before going at this one, as it holds pertinent information. This question asked the following and gave the following info;

1. An MMSI number is a unique number that represents a ship. A ship
   sends out different information in unique Message types. I am
   interested in only Message_ID 1's and 3's as they have Latitudinal
   and Longitudinal Information.

   MMSI's will be reoccuring in this database (as demonstrated in the data above) (this data can be found through the link if you would like to see it)
   Problem is, I need information about the ship which is unfortunately only available in Message_ID 5's. such as Vessel_name and Ship_type.
2. Ship_Type might change! In which case it must reflect the later date
3. I only need ships which fall within the following latitude and
   longitude: **Where Latitude > 55 and Latitude <85 and Longitude > 50 and Longitude < 141;**

****This is the part that has changed! I now need all records that share in an MMSI that has the correct constraints. so for example the following record:****

```
MMSI     Message_ID    Time     Ship_Type  Vessel_Name   Latitude   Longitude

2225555      1       2012-09-01     NULL      NULL       25.432345  145.123343
```

***which was disregarded last time will now be kept as a result of the MMSI number 2225555 having had a record within the latitude and longitudes specified.***

The following Query worked for all the specifications in the last question: [SQL AdvancedQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850908/sql-advancedquery)

```
; WITH positions AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Message_ID
       , "Time"
       , Latitude
       , Longitude
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID IN (1, 3)
  AND    Latitude  > 55
  AND    Latitude  < 85
  AND    Longitude > 50
  AND    Longitude < 141
)
, details AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Ship_Type
       , Vessel_Name
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY MMSI ORDER BY "Time" DESC) As row_num
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID = 5
)
SELECT positions.MMSI
     , positions.Message_ID
     , positions."Time"
     , details.Ship_Type
     , details.Vessel_Name
     , positions.Latitude
     , positions.Longitude
FROM   positions
 INNER
  JOIN details
    ON details.MMSI    = positions.MMSI
   AND details.row_num = 1 -- Limit to "latest" ship details per MMSI
```

I just need a slight adjustment. I am not a programmer.. So adjusting a query of this complexity for me is not at this moment possible.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You need another join to the same table to pull back all the records with an MMSI that is in the result of your existing query. Something like this should do it:

```
; WITH positions AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Message_ID
       , "Time"
       , Latitude
       , Longitude
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID IN (1, 3)
  AND    Latitude  > 55
  AND    Latitude  < 85
  AND    Longitude > 50
  AND    Longitude < 141
)
, all_positions AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Message_ID
       , "Time"
       , Latitude
       , Longitude
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID IN (1, 3)
)
, details AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Ship_Type
       , Vessel_Name
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY MMSI ORDER BY "Time" DESC) As row_num
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID = 5
)
SELECT all_positions.MMSI
     , all_positions.Message_ID
     , all_positions."Time"
     , details.Ship_Type
     , details.Vessel_Name
     , all_positions.Latitude
     , all_positions.Longitude
FROM   positions
 INNER
  JOIN details
    ON details.MMSI    = positions.MMSI
   AND details.row_num = 1 -- Limit to "latest" ship details per MMSI
 INNER
  JOIN all_positions 
    ON positions.MMSI    = all_positions.MMSI
```

EDIT (after feedback from Clockwork-Muse):

Your original query will return duplicate rows when a ship reports more than once from within the desired area. To get rid of this, just use DISTINCT in the positions CTE:

```
; WITH positions AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT MMSI
       , Message_ID
       , "Time"
       , Latitude
       , Longitude
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID IN (1, 3)
  AND    Latitude  > 55
  AND    Latitude  < 85
  AND    Longitude > 50
  AND    Longitude < 141
)
, all_positions AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Message_ID
       , "Time"
       , Latitude
       , Longitude
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID IN (1, 3)
)
, details AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Ship_Type
       , Vessel_Name
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY MMSI ORDER BY "Time" DESC) As row_num
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID = 5
)
SELECT all_positions.MMSI
     , all_positions.Message_ID
     , all_positions."Time"
     , details.Ship_Type
     , details.Vessel_Name
     , all_positions.Latitude
     , all_positions.Longitude
FROM   positions
 INNER
  JOIN details
    ON details.MMSI    = positions.MMSI
   AND details.row_num = 1 -- Limit to "latest" ship details per MMSI
 INNER
  JOIN all_positions 
    ON positions.MMSI    = all_positions.MMSI
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this version of the query is flawed - if there is more than one report from inside the given latitude/longitude, you'll get a Cartesian product.  This is one time I recommend the use of the `DISTINCT` clause (inside the `positions` CTE - oh, and the lat/long from there aren't referenced in the final `SELECT`, either).

Comment: Actually, no, you won't get a cartesian product. I do agree, however, that you would get duplicate rows. However, I based my answer on the assumption that the output from the original query was what the OP wanted, which is what he explicitly stated..

Comment: It is to be expected that there will be more then one report within the given latitude/longitude for each MMSI. I need every record that occurs there. Each MMSI represents a ship at a given point (lat and lon). In essence, reoccuring MMSI numbers within my study area will show me where a given ship has been.

Comment: Why not swap the first 2 CTE's around. All positions first, then the second CTE can use the first as it's base (less repeated code)?

Comment: dpalm - Fine, in that case my original answer will do the trick.

Comment: what do you mean by swap the first 2 CTE's around?

Comment: That wouldn't make any difference, unless I'm missing something. My original answer is what you want.

Comment: the original answer actually didn't work as intended. MMSI's should be recurring, as a single ship (which is represented by an MMSI) sends out many Message's at different stages of its voyage. Hence each Message corresponds to a unique record in the data set. The first query produces multiple copies of a single record.

Comment: I am trying out the second query you posted as we speak. From what I understand though it will select only one record for each MMSI because of the word distinct? If so it won't work either.Perhaps just having it distinct on the latitudes and longitudes. Hence it will not produce more then one result per location

Comment: @dpalm - The `DISTINCT` is in the proper spot (on the 'has a position in the designated zone' CTE).  However, due to the fact that the lat/long are still being included in the CTE, you're still going to get duplicated results.

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH valid_positions AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Message_ID
       , "Time"
       , Latitude
       , Longitude
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Latitude  > 55
  AND    Latitude  < 85
  AND    Longitude > 50
  AND    Longitude < 141
)
, positions AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Message_ID
       , "Time"
       , Latitude
       , Longitude
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID IN (1, 3)
  AND    EXISTS (
           SELECT *
           FROM   valid_positions
           WHERE  valid_positions.MMSI = DecodedCSVMessages_Staging.MMSI
         )
)
, details AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Ship_Type
       , Vessel_Name
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY MMSI ORDER BY "Time" DESC) As row_num
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID = 5
)
SELECT positions.MMSI
     , positions.Message_ID
     , positions."Time"
     , details.Ship_Type
     , details.Vessel_Name
     , positions.Latitude
     , positions.Longitude
FROM   positions
 INNER
  JOIN details
    ON details.MMSI    = positions.MMSI
   AND details.row_num = 1 -- Limit to "latest" ship details per MMSI
```

There's now a 3rd CTE being used.

1. `valid_positions`: **any** records where the co-ordinates fit
   your criteria, for any `Message_ID`  2)
2. `positions`: all records where `Message_ID` equals 1 or 3 **and** there is a record in corresponding `MMSI` in `valid_positions`
3. `details`: unchanged from before. Shows the "latest" ship/vessel details (`Message_ID` = 5)

Comment: @dpalm Are temporary tables an option?